# Cannot restore due to older version of iOS

Tags: restore

I got the iPhone 6s this afternoon and tried to restore the backup from iPhone 6 which is on iCloud. 6s could not restore the backup because 6 was running iOS 9.0.2 and 6s was not. I set it up as a new phone (both have the same name) and upgraded to iOS 9.0.2.

Is there a way to use the old phone's backup?

Answer (score 2):

Now that you've upgraded the phone, you should be able to go in to Settings > General > Erase All Content and Settings.    This will reset the phone like new, except having the latest version installed.    When it restarts, you'll be able to restore from your newer backup.